# I am trying to create an automator run shell script that purges memory and its not working

Tags: shell, applescript, automator

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "sudo"
        keystroke return
        keystroke "purge"
        keystroke return
    end tell:

end tell
```

Comment: Why do you want to use Applescript - there is no GUI or other application involved? I would make a `bash` script that just does `sudo purge`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to use Automator and Applescript and things when you can do that perfectly well in a `bash` shell script.

If you copy this file and save it on your Desktop as `purgenow`

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /usr/sbin/purge
```

then start Terminal and make the script executable like this

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/purgenow
```

you will be able to double-click it and run the script.

Answer (score 0):

The command with the sudo, should really only work if you have adminstrator rights on your account, or are logged in as root, as normally you'd be prompted for a password, you'll have a hard time entering the password for the shell - utility from AppleScript.

Instead, you can excempt the whole sudo command, as you can have the do shell script event take care of that for you, either  by specifying the password by performing a do shell script with **administrator privileges** and enter the account name that holds the administrator rights, and password, when prompted.

You can also specify *predicates* to the `do shell script` event that lets you specify both username and password, to get rid of the prompt for password dialog, and have the purge command run automatically with administrator privileges.

It may under some circumstances be feasible to prepend the `do shell script`event with `tell me`, for the case that the `do shell script` event is called from within an application block, (which is bad style really, and should be avoided whenever possible).

```
do shell script "/usr/sbin/purge" with administrator privileges use name "Admin" password "password"
```

You can read about the `do shell script` event in the Standard Additions dictionary of Script Editor. There is also a Technical Note, you may wish to skim: [Technical Note TN2065: do shell script in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html).